# How do I append a line to a method of a class file in php?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm creating a cli command in Laravel and I need to append a line of code like this :

```
$this->app->register('App\Providers\AccountingRepositoryServiceProvider');
```

to a method e.g. `register` inside an already existing php class file like this :
*app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use ...

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    ...

    public function register()
    {

        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

What is the best way to do this?
Doing this by Laravel or pure PHP doesn't matter.

The main goal is to append a string inside a file in a specific position.

Is this possible by regex?

Comment: Is this a class generator? If not I'm wondering why you would wnt this

Comment: Why would you programmaticly update a php class? If you are creating a package, you can use [automatic discovery](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/packages#package-discovery) instead.

Comment: @Jerodev, unless this a CLI tool generating classes, we wouldn't want to do that

Comment: yes I'm creating a cli command using laravel command generator

Comment: Subclass AppServiceProvider and redefine the method there

Comment: @GordonM To register a custom provider we can't do that in laravel. The right way is to update the main provider class called AppServiceProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solve it by a regex like this :

```
/function register\(.*\)\s*{/
```

First I find the position of the first line of the method in the class by `preg_match` (with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag to have the position), and then insert the code to that position by `substr_replace` (with zero length to have the effect of inserting) :

```
preg_match('/function register\(.*\)\s*{/', $classFileContent, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$firstLinePos = strlen($matches[0][0]) + $matches[0][1];
$newClassFileContent = substr_replace($classFileContent, $codeToInsert, $firstLinePos, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an awesome composer package which can generate everything you need in your classes right here: https://github.com/nette/php-generator

It's pretty easy to use too, check this from the docs:

```
<?php

$class = new Nette\PhpGenerator\ClassType('Demo');

$class
    ->setFinal()
    ->setExtends('ParentClass')
    ->addImplement('Countable')
    ->addTrait('Nette\SmartObject')
    ->addComment("Description of class.\nSecond line\n")
    ->addComment('@property-read Nette\Forms\Form $form');

// to generate PHP code simply cast to string or use echo:
echo $class;
```

Just save the `$class` string into a file!

Comment: I don't want to create a new class but update an already existing class

Comment: If you are familiar with laravel, I just want to creating a custom ServiceProvider using the laravel cli tool. I need to introduce that custom provider to the laravel by updating the AppServiceProvider as I said.